# Removing from a Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a remove from a binary tree function. I'm kinda lost so I'm trying to handle it case by case, starting with if the value I'm trying to remove is in the root of the BST. To test my function, I am first calling a printcontents() function that prints all the contents of the tree, then I'm calling remove(8) [8 being the value in my root at the moment), and then calling printcontents() again. The way I'm doing it is by trying to replace the root with the "right-most" value in the left side of the tree. When I call printcontents the second time, it prints the new root value correctly, but when it continues printing the contents and reaches the point where that value used to be, it has a random long number "-572......"(although i don't think the number matters) and then my program crashes. I see my root's value is being replaced, but what happens afterwards??

Here's my remove function:

```
void BinarySearchTree::remove(int value) {

      Node* tmp = head;
      Node* tmp2 = head;


     if (head->data == value && head->left != NULL) {

        tmp=tmp->left;

        while (tmp->right != NULL) {
            tmp=tmp->right;

        }

        while (tmp2->right->right != NULL) {
            tmp2=tmp2->right;

        }

        if (tmp->left == NULL) {     

        head->data = tmp->data;
        tmp2->right = NULL;
        delete tmp;

        }

        if (tmp->left != NULL) {

            head->data = tmp->data;
            tmp2->right = tmp->left;
            delete tmp;

        }




}
```

It's obviously incomplete, but I'm testing it to only handle the case in which the root is removed and replaced by the right-most value in the left side of the tree (assuming there is a left side, which there is), and I feel like logically it should be working, so perhaps it is when I "delete tmp" that things go wrong. I don't know whether posting my whole program will be necessary, but if so, let me know!

Comment: Never been ignored so badly lol

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest that instead of writing out for root, why don't you treat the case as it is dealt with in CLRS : That is two distinct cases. 
1. When node to be deleted is a leaf 
2. When node to be deleted is non-leaf(in that case replace it with inorder successor/predecessor).

The root deletion obviously falls under the second case. This is just a suggestion.